# strace: Any sense in `dup2(A, B); close(B)`?

Tags: java, jvm, file-descriptor, system-calls, strace

I'm trying to understand a `strace` of an Java application server running in a oracle JVM.

I often see these lines:

```
[pid 10465] 23:04:59.658453 dup2(215, 274) = 274
[pid 10465] 23:04:59.658616 close(274)  = 0
```

In this case `215` is a UNIX socket:

```
java    10387 XXX  215u  unix 0xffff880037962cc0      0t0 153294021 socket
```

FD `274` is an *open* TCP socket.

These "call pairs" repeat multiple times with the same `A` socket over multiple minutes.

My understanding of `dup2(A, B)` is that it creates an file descriptor `B` pointing/refering to the same file/socket `A`, closing `B` first if it's still open.

[Opengroup says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)

> The dup2() function shall cause the file descriptor fildes2 to refer to the same open file description as the file descriptor fildes and to share any locks, and shall return fildes2. If fildes2 is already a valid open file descriptor, it shall be closed first, unless fildes is equal to fildes2 in which case dup2() shall return fildes2 without closing it.

My only guess so far is, that this a strange, unoptimized behaviour of the JVM. Isn't it? Which sense does it make.

If necessary, I'll add more context calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sequence provides a thread-safe way to close a socket.

`dup2` allows to close a socket without releasing a file descriptor. This can be a lengthy operation due to untransmitted data and a long linger interval. `dup2(A, B)` is an atomic equivalent to

```
close(B);
fcntl(A, F_DUPFD, B);
```

i.e. `B` remains a valid descriptor at any time. Keeping the file descriptor valid is essential until all threads that have acquired this descriptor complete outstanding I/O operations.

`fd` being duplicated (215 in your case) is a special marker socket in `shutdown` state. It is created once for the only purpose of closing other sockets via `dup2`.
Once `dup2` is complete, any reads from the original `fd` (274) will return EOF and any writes to it will get an error.

Java maintains a use counter for each file descriptor. Threads increment this counter when acquiring a file descriptor and decrement it when they are done with I/O.
As soon as use counter drops to 0, Java calls `close` to release the file descriptor and make it available to the OS.

Java NIO implementation uses the same technique to close files.
Though I haven't seen this pattern other than in JDK source code.

Comment: So `dup2()` internally does not call `close(B)` actually, but makes a bit more special stuff (setting a "closed"-flag e.g.)? Because your answer "`As soon as use counter becomes 0 [...]`" reads as the `B` socket is closed while the underlying file descriptor (table, struct, whatever) remains until it's no longer used. The phase `special marker socket` means, 215 has been opened only to close other sockets? Does this `dup2()-close` pattern also apply to file descriptors? Would you be so kind and add a reference to this thread-safe close pattern? Please update your answer rather than commenting?